# Java upload throughput measurements

Tags: java, http, upload, apache-httpclient-4.x

I would like to do some http upload throughput measurements. I recently discovered the Apache httpcore libray provides a `getMetrics` method in the `DefaultBHttpClientConnection` class. This method returns an `HttpConnectionMetrics` object.

However, I cannot figure out what the value returned by `getSentBytesCount` from the `HttpConnectionMetrics` represents.

Is it the data that has been uploaded and received on the server side? Or is it only what has been pushed to the network interface? Is it 'real time'? And finally, does it take into account packets in error at the tcp level?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getSentBytesCount` in `HttpConnectionMetrics` represents the number of bytes written to the underlying socket / channel. Beyond that JRE can exert no control of how many bytes end up pushed to the network interface.

Comment: Do you know any way to achieve this in Java? If not, do you know if this is easyly possible in C/C++? Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: I personally do not know of a way of controlling what gets written to the physical network interface in Java. I suspect it should be possible with straight C but unlikely to be easy